# ASP.NET Response.Cookie is being set when I only want to get

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have a page that checks the value of a cookie being set on the `HttpResponse` and depending on certain criteria, the page might modify that value. The logic is a basically:

```
If Response.Cookie("foo").Value = "bar" Then
    Response.Cookie("foo").Value += "rawr"
End If
```

Apparently that any attempt to get a cookie out of `Response.Cookie` results in that cookie being set on the response. In the following code, *even though nothing is being set or added to the* `Response.Cookie` *collection*...

```
Dim c As HttpCookie = Response.Cookies("rawr")
Response.Cookies.Get("foo")
```

...the response still contains...

```
Set-Cookie: rawr=; path=/
Set-Cookie: foo=; path=/
```

So what that means for my original code snippet is that if the cookie value doesn't equal `foo`, the cookie gets emptied (since getting the cookie in the `If` sets it to be blank and the conditional never sets it to `+="bar"`.

**What is the proper way to inspect and modify cookies in the** `Response.Cookie` **collection without unintentionally setting them to blank?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to be checking Request.Cookies("foo"), not Response.Cookies.("foo").

If you truly meant what you wrote, you could have earlier logic holding values in variables that would determine the final output cookie setting.